# Django: The page shows "(<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at ...>)" at variable location in a template

Tags: django, forms, templates, checkbox

I was trying include a checkbox on my template, but it showed me some text on the browser instead.

I have a form (forms.py) that contains boolean field, e.g:

```
Class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='my_checkbox'),
```

and I have the following in my templates/my_app/my_form_template.py:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    {{ form.my_checkbox }}
<form>
```

In the browser after running the server, I've got:
`(<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x0000014BE3CF9208>,)`

The CharField and ChoiceField work perfectly except BooleanField. What is a way to represent a checkbox on the template?

I've tried {{ form }} in the template and it shows the checkbox, but I wish to custom the attributes of the checkbox.

Comment: Do you, by any chance wrote a *comma* at the end of the `forms.BooleanField(..)`?

Comment: Yes. I removed and it works, thank you! I didn't realized it since it did not affect my above previous CharFields and ChoiceFields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *comma* at the end of the field that causes an error. Removing it would fix the problem.