# Django.forms.fields.booleanfield Object at when iterating through a list of fields

Tags: python, django, forms, iteration, jinja2

I want to iterate through a list of checkboxes. When I use a single checkbox it works, but when I iterate through the checkboxes, I get

```
<DJANGO.FORMS.FIELDS.BOOLEANFIELD OBJECT AT 0X7FA2DA62B470> <DJANGO.FORMS.FIELDS.BOOLEANFIELD OBJECT AT 0X7FA2DA5A5940>
```

It shouldn't be a list or tuple issue like in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314626/django-the-page-shows-django-forms-fields-booleanfield-object-at-at-v) or similar questions I found.

**my forms.py:**

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):

    toggles = [forms.BooleanField(label="A Checkbox", required=False), 
               forms.BooleanField(label="A second Checkbox", required=False)]

    single_toggle = forms.BooleanField(label="A single Checkbox", required=False)
```

**my template:**

```
        {% for toggle in form.toggles %}
            {{ toggle }}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ form.single_toggle }}
```

Expected output: Three checkboxes

Actual output: 
`<DJANGO.FORMS.FIELDS.BOOLEANFIELD OBJECT AT 0X7FA2DA62B470> <DJANGO.FORMS.FIELDS.BOOLEANFIELD OBJECT AT 0X7FA2DA5A5940>` and a single checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out after more research, as described [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/):

**New code in forms.py**

```
class PhoneAdaptForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(3):
            self.fields['new_toggle_' + str(i)] = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.CheckboxInput, label="Try NO. " + str(i), required=False)

    def get_init_fields(self):
        for field_name in self.fields:
            if field_name.startswith('new_toggle_'):
                yield self[field_name]
```

And then the **template:**

```
        {% for new_field in form.get_init_fields %}
            {{ new_field }}
        {% endfor %}
```

This gives me three checkboxes.